# Unable to open HTML href link in Safari/iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, cordova

I have created a simple application using Phonegap in XCode using HTML. My code looks like this:

```
<dd><a href="tel:0674-673425">Office Number</a></dd>
<dd><a href="tel:+9945637826">Personal Number</a></dd>
<dd><a href="http://google.com">Log in to your Mail ID</a></dd>
```

The first two links are working fine. I am able to dial a number; but the last line is not working. It seems like disabled. In the mobile, after running, it's showing "Log in to your Mail ID" as a tab but nothing happens when I click it.The web address is not going to  the Safari browser.

Please help. how can I integrate  this link to Safari browser in iPhone like the first two lines.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u have to implement child browser in ur application......https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser
 it have a option of opening the link in safari also .....if u have any query plz feel free to ask .....

Comment: Thanks a lot Varun. 

But this child browser  plugin is only for Iphone ? and is it so , then there is no use of using Jquerymobile.Because we call it as hybrid. I only have Iphone to taste the app. Please clarify.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot Varun again ... :)

Comment: if u feel the answer is correct then plz mark the answer as correct and also upvote it .....:)